# Mongoose Populate Use or Not Use?

Tags: node.js, performance, mongodb

### Definitions

I have Post Model in mongoose:

```
{
    sender: ObjectId, // User Id
    title : String,
    ...
}
```

I want to list my Post with their User's title.
And I have two choice:

1- List Posts > Extract unique Senders > Query for User titles > Replace Ids with Titles in results

> One query to list `Post`s and one query to list unique `User`s

2- Use mongoose populate method in schema: `sender: {type:ObjectId, ref: User},`
And use the new populated value for `sender` in result like: `sender.title`

> Base on how mongoose populate values may has different number of queries

### Question!:

When mongoose populate 'sender' property, What does it do?
Because I need to use the best option for my project (And readable one)!

1- Use a new query for each Id

> To List 1000 Post we have 1001 queries!! even when we have repeated users!!

2- Or Use a query for each unique Id

> To List 1000 Post from 100 Users we have 101 queries!

3- Or even better list unique User ids and query all together (like choice one)

> We have only 2 queries!! (the best if possible)

Comment: *"When mongoose populate 'sender' property, What does it do?"* Enable debug mode and see for yourself.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/31729320/5016828 sends my answers. but you, if you know answer whether just quite!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 3 - Mongoose will get the posts and then query users exactly once with the $in operator.

Even after doing this, the performance of doing it manually will always be better because mongoose blocks the event emitter for the period of time it takes to complete both the queries whereas your code will block it individually for a shorter time, which has better performance. you can use [blocked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blocked) to benchmark is

Comment: Thanks. And you says about [blocked module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blocked) I read it's page but I can't realized how to use it in my case!

Comment: just start an instance on the main file of the app (app/server.js). It will keep reporting the blocked timings